# How to add zeros to uneven list

Tags: list-manipulation

I'm reading a book on MMA and it has an example

`Range @ Range @ 3` that produces `{{1}, {1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}}`

What if I want to make it as matrix 3 x 3, like so `{{1, 0, 0}, {1, 2, 0}, {1, 2, 3}}`. This is perhaps very simple but most functions that I've learned so far operate on rectangular entities.

---

*Keywords*: ragged array rectangular reshape append padleft padright

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1.** I think a didactical answer with relatively simple and often used functions would be something like:

```
ls = {{1}, {1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}};

n = 3;
Map[Join[#, Table[0, {n - Length[#]}]] &, ls]

Out[107]= {{1, 0, 0}, {1, 2, 0}, {1, 2, 3}}
```

**2.** We can also see `ls` as the nonzero elements in a sparse matrix and program this:

```
In[103]:= Normal@SparseArray[Position[ls, _Integer] -> Flatten[ls]]

Out[103]= {{1, 0, 0}, {1, 2, 0}, {1, 2, 3}}
```

**3.** And, of course, we can use the specialized function `PadRight`. (As mentioned by Kuba in a comment.)

Comment: may be also `ArrayReshape[#, {n}, 0] & /@ ls`; and `Table[0, n]` seems easier than `Table[0, {n}]`

Comment: @garej Sure. But since the user is a beginner it is better to give instructive solutions than solutions that have to be deciphered.

Answer (score 14):

Some very complex answers. Not sure why you wouldn't simply use `PadRight` which was apparently referenced in a comment that is no longer there.

```
PadRight[{{1}, {1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}}]

(* {{1, 0, 0}, {1, 2, 0}, {1, 2, 3}} *)
```

Comment: This is what I think after first glance. :)

Answer (score 6):

In:

```
(*Method 1*)
Table[Range[3], 3] // LowerTriangularize
Array[#2 &, {3, 3}] // LowerTriangularize
Array[#1 &, {3, 3}] // Transpose // LowerTriangularize
BoxMatrix[1] Range[3] // Transpose // LowerTriangularize
BoxMatrix[1] + Range[0, 2] // Transpose // LowerTriangularize

(*Method 2*)    
DiagonalMatrix[Range[#], # - 3] & /@ Range[3] // Plus @@ # &

(*Method 3*)    
Table[FromDigits@Range[n] 10^(3 - n), {n, Range[3]}] // IntegerDigits

(*Method 4*)
10^Range[0, 2] // Map[# Quotient[FromDigits@Range[3], #] &] // 
  Reverse // IntegerDigits
```

Out:

```
{{1, 0, 0}, {1, 2, 0}, {1, 2, 3}}
{{1, 0, 0}, {1, 2, 0}, {1, 2, 3}}
{{1, 0, 0}, {1, 2, 0}, {1, 2, 3}}
{{1, 0, 0}, {1, 2, 0}, {1, 2, 3}}
{{1, 0, 0}, {1, 2, 0}, {1, 2, 3}}
{{1, 0, 0}, {1, 2, 0}, {1, 2, 3}}
{{1, 0, 0}, {1, 2, 0}, {1, 2, 3}}
{{1, 0, 0}, {1, 2, 0}, {1, 2, 3}}
```